Optimizing TCL binary scan for parsing TCP packet payload
I am iterating over a TCP payload using binary scan using code similar to this:
set offset 42
binary scan ${payload} @${offset}c some_len
inr offset 1

# do something here

incr offset ${some_len}

binary scan ${payload} @${offset}S someother_len
incr offset 2
set nested_offset 0
set nested_cnt 0
set my_list [list]
while { [expr {${nested_offset} < ${someother_len}}] } {
  binary scan ${payload} @${offset}H4 some_hex
  if { [lsearch -sorted -inline ${checklist} $some_hex] eq "" } {
    lappend my_list ${some_hex}
    incr nested_cnt
  }
  incr cipher_offset 2
  incr field_offset 2
}

binary scan ${payload} @${offset}S third_len
incr offset 2

# do something else here
#...many more binary scans with incremented offsets.



My question is around optimizing this code as much as possible.
Currently this tcl code averages about 1.4M CPU cycles to execute.
I have done a fair bit of research and have looked at implementing K combinators where possible but, have so far been unsuccessful, as every attempt to do so results in TCL errors.  I have made a few other changes but have not been able to significantly improve the performance.
Do you see any obvious changes I could make to this code?  Some way of shortening the $payload as I iterate over it?
EDIT:
I probably should have included a few extra details.

The code referenced above is already running in a proc.
This is running in the "neutered" TCL environment of F5 iRules.
Which means:

I am limited to whatever features and function are in TCL 8.4.
There are some TCL commands that are disabled in the iRules execution space; "dict" is one of those not available to me.




Putting it in a proc instead of top level code lets the bytecode compiler kick in for more efficient execution; or so I've been lead to believe.

The absolutely first thing to try is putting the code you are measuring inside a procedure. That enables many optimisations (because it means there is a local variable table that can be accessed by index).
Secondly, binary scan is not actually heavily optimised. Using string range to get the slice of string to parse may be faster (along with a simpler binary scan); it will likely be faster in Tcl 9.0 as that does efficient string slicing. But that definitely requires measurement; my intuition might be wrong!
Thirdly, if you are searching for presence of values in a list as a presence test, it is probably faster to put those as keys in a dictionary (for a one-off cost of building the dictionary) and then using dict exists to test for presence. Dictionaries are backed by hash tables and, as such, are probably rather fast. Again, you need to measure to confirm my intuition.

You reveal in comments some more critical details. In particular, you're using an 8.4 dialect. That is unfortunate; it was missing quite a few operations that would have helped. In particular, dictionaries are an 8.5 feature (that is, totally absent) and info exists was not optimised at all and was actually very slow.
I don't know whether 8.4 would handle string range efficiently on a byte array value; it might but I've not worked with code that old for a long time.
The way to accelerate the set inclusion test is to generate an array with entries for all the values you ever might ask about, using a value of 1 for the keys you want in and a value of 0 for the others. For all two-byte values, that should be 65536 entries. Then you can just do a simple array element read, which is fast in 8.4 (it was part of the set of things optimised back in 8.0 in the original bytecode implementation).
I don't remember if array element names are allowed to contain NULs in 8.4; they might. If so, you could perhaps avoid doing the binary scan until after you know you have a hit, by using binary strings as array element names (since you're not limited to numbers in associative arrays). Worth testing.

I probably should have included a few extra details.

The code referenced above is already running in a proc.
This is running in the "neutered" TCL environment of F5 iRules.  Which means:
a. I am limited to whatever features and function are in TCL 8.4
b. There are some TCL commands that are disabled in the iRules execution space; "dict" is one of those not available to me.

I'll edit theoriginal question to include these details.

Wouldn't string range "mess up" the binary data that I have in the $payload variable buffer?
And what exactly do you mean by "a simpler binary scan"? Like collect all of the bytes for this TCP header/option in a binary scan $payload @${offset}H${hex_len} my_next_data_chunk and then string range that data?

string range either knows how to be smart with binary data already, or really ought to! In Tcl, binary data is just a subtype of string...

Oh, in 8.4? Good luck then. There were a lot of operations that weren't optimised heavily back then.
